# how to instantiate dynamically asynchronous service workers in java

Tags: java, dictionary, asynchronous, static, instance

I am working for a bank and I develop and application with Java 1.4.
I have to call asynchronously some certain AS400 services, so I decided to use this approach: I create a `private static Map` and I populate it in a `static` block. When I have to call the instance, I get the name of the service to call as parameter, search if the map contains that String as key and instantiate the service class.

The problem I've encountered is that, having many asynchronous processes working at the same time on the same JVM, they migth retrieve the same service class instance at the same time.

For example:

- at time 1 process A calls WBX133 and releases it at time 10
- at time 3 process B calls WBX220 and releases it at time 8
- at time 4 process C calls WBX133 and releases it at time 13

Since the map is static, I will provide to the processes always the same instance of the worker class, however, each process will have a different input and expecting different output from the same service.

Here is the code I've explained:

```
public class AS400ServiceFactory {
   private static Map serviceMap;

   static {
       serviceMap = new HashMap();

       serviceMap.put("WBX133", new Wbx133Service());
       serviceMap.put("WBX134", new Wbx134Service());
       serviceMap.put("WBX220", new Wbx220Service()); 
       serviceMap.put("WBX360", new Wbx360Service());
       serviceMap.put("WBX370", new Wbx370Service());
       serviceMap.put("WBX371", new Wbx371Service());
   }

   public static AS400Container getInstance(String serviceName) {
       ASService service = null;        
       if (serviceMap.containsKey(serviceName)) {
           service = (ASService) serviceMap.get(serviceName);
       }
   }
}
```

A quick (but, in my opinion, not elegant) solution would be, instead of having a static map, just:

```
public class AS400ServiceFactory {
   public static AS400Container getInstance(String serviceName) {
      ASService service = null;

      if (("WBX133").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx133Service();
      }
      if (("WBX134").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx134Service();
      }
      if (("WBX220").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx220Service();
      }
      if (("WBX360").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx360Service();
      }
      if (("WBX370").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx370Service();
      }
      if (("WBX371").equals(serviceName)) {
          service = new Wbx371Service();
      }
   }
}
```

In this way I won't have anymore the problem of having the same instance always. However, I will have in the future something like 60-70 services and having a 60-70 `if-else if` is not really readable.

Any suggestion is apreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: So you want new instance each time?

Comment: You can store a map of factories, each having the responsibility to create one of the `WbxXXXService` class.

Comment: "they migth retrieve the same service class instance at the same time" - is that a problem? Aren't they thead-safe? Do they have some inner state that prevents two concurrent service "transactions" ?

Comment: @Fildor apparently they are not thread-safe. Since the managing of the processes and how they call the services has been implemented by another group of programmers (who are not working with me anymore) I don't have the control over that part. For this reason, the only practical solution is to have a new instance each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create a map of service factories and then use it.

```
public class AS400ServiceFactory {
  private static Map factories = createFactories();

  private static Map createFactories() {
    Map factories = new HashMap();
    factories.put("WBX133", new ServiceFactory(){ public ASService create() { return new Wbx133Service(); } });
    factories.put("WBX134", new ServiceFactory(){ public ASService create() { return new Wbx134Service(); } });
    factories.put("WBX220", new ServiceFactory(){ public ASService create() { return new Wbx220Service(); } });
    // More factories here
    return factories;
  }

  public static AS400Container getInstance(String serviceName) {
    ServiceFactory factory = (ServiceFactory)factories.get(serviceName);
    ASService service = null;
    if (factory != null) {
      service = factory.create();
    }
    // Rest of the method
  }
  private interface ServiceFactory {
    ASService create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Olivier for the answer. I think it is a really nice and elegant solution for my problem. I have just to make a quick note, method create() in the AS400ContainerFactory interface should return an instance of ASService instead of AS400Container, because every service I have is a sub-class of ASService. Anyway, your solution is good and that is why I will mark it as accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @FrancescoSgaramella You're welcome! And I just fixed it with your comments in mind: I was indeed not very careful with the names. Sorry for that.